# Monit reports "failed to stop" before timeout

Tags: timeout, monit

I am starting and stopping [a process](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) via monit with the following syntax:

```
stop program = "..." with timeout 90 seconds
```

Everything works well, except that Monit always reports `failed to stop` after exactly one minute:

From `/var/log/monit.log`:

```
[EST Nov 11 11:04:09] info     : 'myprocess' stop: /bin/su
[EST Nov 11 11:05:09] error    : 'myprocess' failed to stop
[EST Nov 11 11:05:10] info     : 'myprocess' stop action done
```

I obviously want it to wait 90 seconds, not 60 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in Monit: https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issue/109/failed-to-stop-always-after-60-seconds
Updating to Monit >= 5.9 should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your Monit daemon check interval is probably 60 seconds, so the check cycle occurs before your timeout.

```
set daemon 60
```

Can you post your entire Monit config? Is there a reason you need a 90-second timeout to stop a process?

By default, Monit waits 30 seconds for start/stop commands when it's looking at the process listing. Can you try a shorter `with timeout`?

Comment: Yes, that's it! What would be a sensible value for this setting? I need such a long timeout because the process I am monitoring is a background job queue, and it might take 60 seconds or longer to let a job finish before restarting.

Comment: How often do you wish for Monit to poll your system? Try 120 seconds if 2-minute intervals is good for you.

Comment: Well no... if I set a stop timeout of 90 seconds, I would need it to check exactly then. With a daemon timeout of 120 seconds, it will check after 120 seconds, no?

Comment: Try it and see!

Comment: I tried 120 and 20 as daemon timeouts, same behavior with both settings. Confusing...